# How to detect player deaths in 1.16 and detect who died

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

I'm making a murder mystery map, and when someone dies I want to set them to spectator mode. Testfor doesn't work in this version, and many of the other answers have not worked, like > /scoreboard objectives add Deaths stat.deaths
I've inputted this, and it counts deaths, but I don't know how to apply this data to change the gamemode of the person who died. How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Aqade works best when you can show that you've tried *something*.

Comment: Yea, I thought it was fluff to put what I've already tried in the question. IT's my first time so I didn't know how, but if I need to ask again I will put an effort into explaining what I've tried. Thanks!

Comment: @kanosereg We would prefer it if you took the opportunity to edit this post to improve its current state, even if you’ve already found an answer. This will make the question more relatable for the community.

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a [scoreboard objective](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Objectives) that tracks deaths, and then [setting anyone with a score of at least 1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) (0 being that you haven't died yet) [to spectator mode](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/gamemode).

```
/gamemode spectator @a[scores={deaths=1..}]
```

(Assuming `death` is your deaths scoreboard objective)

[You can then set the value of that score to 0 once a round ends to remove said force-spectatoring](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/scoreboard).

```
/scoreboard players set @a[scores={deaths=1..}] deaths 0
/gamemode adventure @a[scores={deaths=0}]
```